# java define println for class object

Tags: java, class

In C++, one can implement the `ostream operator <<` to be able to define how a class can be output to the stream `cout << Class`.

Is it possible in java to do something like `out.println(Class)`?

Comment: `toString` helps you

Comment: override `toString` method for you object

Comment: why is OP downvoted? he comes from C++

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Can't do C++ developers any research?

Comment: I'd down vote your comment for terrible structure.  I tried 'java override println' and 'java overload operator" and a few others.  Didn't find a solution.

Comment: So you never searched for the most obvious 'java print object'? And I didn't vote on this question, so blame other users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.out.print()` calls the `toString()` method of the object passed to it. If you override the `toString()` method in your class, you can implement a custom behaviour there. Your class inherit the method from `Object`. Every class has `Object` as a superclass in java. Below is the default implementation.

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

The print method (`System.out.print(Object obj)`) looks like this

```
public void print(Object obj) {
    write(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

and the `String.valueOf(Object obj)` method finally calls `toString()`.

Comment: Thank you!  Appreciate the answer!  Works perfectly :D